# Resolve "Path not found" error for include_path within project source

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm migrating a project over to phpstorm, but I'm not sure how to set this situation up correctly and can't find clear documentation.

My project structure is like this:

```
\projectroot         <-- My phpstorm projects points at this directory
--\public_html       <-- The web server points here
----\.user.ini       <-- has include_path="C:\sites\projectroot\source"
----\index.php       <-- and a few other php files
--\source            <-- The folder containing real code
----\application.php <-- One example file
--\content
```

`index.php` includes files using `require_once 'application.php'` and within the source folder, files routinely do things like `require_once 'model/user.php'` to include other files within the source folder.  How do I correctly get phpstorm to resolve these includes for this project only.  I see that there is an includes section under Settings > PHP, but it's not clear if that is per project, and looks like that is maybe supposed to reference  external libraries anyway.

Comment: Yes, `Settings | PHP | Include Paths` is for referencing code that is outside of the project (e.g. 3rd party libraries etc). To answer your question: you cannot resolve it without modifying include/require statements .. or disabling that inspection altogether (which I do in most cases). The reason is simple: IDE does not support such custom folders as reference roots ATM -- all such paths has to be relative current file or project/module root. And these days .. when almost all classes are loaded via autoloaders there is no much movement in improving this aspect.

Comment: For me this inspection is pretty useless (plus, due to autoloading, I only have like 3-5 explicit includes anyway). And even if I do use them, I prefer absolute paths (a bit faster and more safer/secure). Since most likely you have all requests passed through `index.php` (like I do), you could do similar to what I was always doing: define some constant there, e.g. `define('DIR_SRC', dirname(__DIR__) . '\source\');` and then use such constant in all include/require statements, e.g. `require_once DIR_SRC . 'model/user.php'`